# Elixir lists with tuples modifications

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to create the following list:

```
["extract-audio", "audio-format", "mp3"]
```

Based on:

```
options = ["extract-audio", "audio-format": "mp3"]
```

My code to move from the supplied `options` to the preferred list:

```
arguments = Enum.map(options, fn(option) ->
      parametrize(option)
    end) |> List.flatten

def parametrize(arg) when is_tuple(arg), do: Tuple.to_list(arg)
def parametrize(arg) when is_binary(arg), do: arg
```

The returned list is almost correct:

```
["extract-audio", :"audio-format", "mp3"]
```

But, I don't quite understand what the semicolon is doing in front of `audio-format`. And it feels a bit off to create some kind of regex to replace that. Is there perhaps a better solution than my current implementation? I've also thought about maps, but in some cases, I only want an argument and not a key value.

Comment: `:"audio-format"` looks like an atom

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, and we could easily convert that with `Atom.to_String(:"audio-format"). But I don't really want to iterate over all items in the list to see if I need to convert it or not.

Comment: use pattern matching rather than `is_tuple`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need any helper, just use the reducer with multiple clauses. The code below needs one pass through the list and does not require flattening.

```rb
options = ["extract-audio", "audio-format": "mp3"]

options
|> Enum.reduce([], fn            
  {k, v}, acc -> [v, k | acc]
  e, acc -> [e | acc]                   
end)
|> Enum.reverse()

#⇒ ["extract-audio", :"audio-format", "mp3"]
```

You might notice, that `:"audio-format"` is an atom. That’s because *Elixir* did some magic building [`Keyword`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html) out of notation `"foo": "bar`.

```rb
["a-b": 42] == [{:"a-b", 42}]
#⇒ true
```

Comment: Nice. Seems like they might prefer `{k, v}, acc -> [v, Atom.to_String(k) | acc]`

Comment: @JohnColeman might be, but it damages the original values, so I’d leave it as-is for now. I dropped a clarification sentence fwiw.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks! That `keyword` is interesting, something I need to do a bit more research into. What's the idea about `reverse`? Can't you do `{k, v}, acc -> [k, v | acc]` instead?

Comment: `[k, v | acc]` would shuffle the result. The idea is (although the margins here are too small to describe it in detail): lists in [tag:elixir] are **linked lists** and prepending costs less than appending to the list. Without reverse one could do: `acc ++ [k, v]` but this is kinda counter-idiomatic.

Comment: @KevinEtore reversing a list is `O(n)` but building up a list by small concatenations is `O(n^2)`. For a large list the difference is noticeable.

Comment: @JohnColeman this is not precisely correct. `[v, k] ++ acc` instead of `[v, k | acc]` would not result in `O(n²)`. http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#myth--operator--++--is-always-bad

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Good point, though that approach would still require the `reverse`. Thanks for the link. I am just starting out in Elixir but have a background in SML, which despite the different syntax and type discipline has a similar approach to basic functional programming. The idiom of building up a list by consing items to the front of the list and then reversing it at the end is common in SML.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's efficient way, but this works just

replace

```
def parametrize(arg) when is_tuple(arg), do: Tuple.to_list(arg)
```

with

```
def parametrize(arg) when is_tuple(arg) do
  for el <- Tuple.to_list(arg) do
     if is_atom(el), do: Atom.to_string(el), else: el
  end
end
```

Comment: `if` in [tag:elixir] is a code smell, specifically when it’s absolutely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement this

**1. Recursion**

```
def parameterize(list, acc \\ [])
def parameterize([{k, v} | tail], acc) do
  parameterize(tail, [v, k | acc])
end

def parameterize([element | tail], acc) do
  parameterize(tail, [element | acc])
end

def parameterize([], acc), do: acc |> List.flatten |> Enum.reverse()
```

**2. Using Enum.reduce** as answered by Aleksei Matiushkin above

```
options = ["extract-audio", "audio-format": "mp3"]

options
|> Enum.reduce([], fn            
  {k, v}, acc -> [v, k | acc]
  e, acc -> [e | acc]                   
end)
|> Enum.reverse()

#⇒ ["extract-audio", :"audio-format", "mp3"]
```

**3. Using Enum.flat_map**

```
Enum.flat_map(options, fn
  value when is_tuple(value) -> Tuple.to_list(value)
  any -> [any]
end)
```

Any of the three can be used based on the comfort :D